# Flatten composite entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Is it possible to flatten a two-table relationships into a single entity in Entity Framework?

Specifically, (simplified for example) given the following two tables that define a 1-1 relationship

```
create table Foo
(
    Id int not null identity (1, 1)
        constraint PK_Foo_Id primary key (Id),
    Name nvarchar(64) not null,
    BarId int not null
        constraint FK_Bar_Foo foreign key (BarId) references Bar (Id)
)

create table Bar
(
    Id int not null identity (1, 1)
        constraint PK_Bar_Id primary key (Id),
    Value nvarchar(max) not null
)
```

I can easily map this to entities like this

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Bar Bar { get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

But what I would like to map to a single flattened entity

```
public class FlatFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

Notice that only one field from table Bar is mapped to FlatFoo

**Notes**

- The actual tables are larger.
- Since the text value in Bar can get large it would fill index pages quickly, so there are two tables for quicker index searches against Foo.Id and Foo.Name.
- I have looked into Split Entities, but it required both tables have the same primary key.
- I have looked at Complex Types but it works in the opposite manner taking a flat table and splitting into composite entities.
- I am looking to use the Fluent API to perform the mapping.

Can you provide any help in flattening the mapping between two tables and a single entity?

**Update**

Yes, views will work to get a flat entity, but then I am not mapping from tables to entity.  Likewise, from the other side, I know it is possible to map to non-public composition and expose the property that way.  But, I am more interested in learning if EF fluent API is flexible enough to handle the mapping directly than I am in solving a particular issue.

Unfortunately, there is considerable push-back here (at work) to any suggestion of adding anything other than tables to a database (something as basic as views included).  It is typically pointed out that doing so adds additional point of maintenance, increases training for support, adds complexity for basic CRUD and other excuses for not learning the tools available.  It is silly at best, but it is something I have to deal with.  :(

So, as a point of learning for me, is it possible to do this seemingly basic task of directly mapping fields from two arbitrary tables into one entity using EF, fluent API preferred?

Comment: Why not create a SQL VIew and use EF to map the result to FlatFoo?

Comment: None said you have to map entities to *tables*. In fact, using *mapping* as a substitute to proper database design is a *very* strong smell and a strong sign of the [Golden Hammer](http://deviq.com/golden-hammer/) antipattern. Typically another followed antipattern, trying to use LINQ joins to combine the entities and return what the view could return just as easily.

Comment: In other words, you have to cure the push-back. In fact, the justification for  it is *exactly* why you shouldn't map to tables. You force *another two* points of maintenance (mapping, queries), *away* from the original schema (table) that *can't* be deployed concurrently, forcing stronger coupling between code and database. You end up *leaking* the table design into the application's design. Optimizing performance will be hard as it won't be obvious *which* query caused the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't provide a way to map one entity to two tables and then cherry pick from the columns in the way you describe unless the tables share a common key. So as mentioned in the comments, the simplest solution is to create a View and map the entity to that.

```
public class FlatFooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FlatFoo>
{
    public FlatFooMap ()
    {
        ToTable("vwFlatFoo");
        HasKey(t => t.Id);                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer, but you probably won't like it. Or maybe it will provide you the ammunition you need to knock heads together.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.